# UFT 14.0: Java menu is not displayed when clicked

Tags: java, qtp, hp-uft, calypso

[image]

As shown in the above figure, I have to click the down arrow button on left top status bar to show the menu. I have written code which highlights the menu button but the men options are not displayed.

```
JavaWindow("FX Deal Station (User:").JavaMenu("16icon").Select
JavaWindow("FX Deal Station (User:").JavaMenu("16icon").JavaMenu("Back-Office").Select
JavaWindow("FX Deal Station (User:").JavaMenu("16icon").JavaMenu("Back-Office").JavaMenu("BO Window").Select
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Menu is not displayed when used Select or Click. Any other alternates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh the dreaded Calypso' FX Deal Station menu.

Here is the hack which I've used to select menu

```
Call JavaWindow("FX Deal Station (User:").JavaMenu("16icon").Object.doClickOnMenu

JavaWindow("FX Deal Station (User:").JavaMenu("16icon").JavaMenu("Back-Office").JavaMenu("BO Window").Select
```

Comment: @pankaj-jaju could you please create a tag "calypso" and add it to this question? I don't have enough rep to do it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasLeplus - Done